# How can I programmatically (using Apps Script) import lots of contacts into Google Contacts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts

I want to regularly import a changing list of ~500 contacts. I wrote an Apps Script that does this, but it takes longer than 6 minutes because it has to import each contact individually. I can generate a vcard file and import that into Google Contacts in just a few seconds using the web interface, but I don't think there's a programmatic interface to that functionality.

Is there a way to import many contacts at once from Apps Script? I'd like to have it triggered once a week or so and work without intervention or interaction.

Comment: One can have the script save its current state and exit after 5 minutes, to resume again until the job is done. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8608327

Comment: We would need to see what code you currently have in order to help.